# Add multiple Params to action in a Drools rules decision tables using excel

Tags: java, excel, jboss, drools

I have a action in a Drools rules desicion table in excel file and this invoque a method in java. This method need 2 parameters for add the data in this method variables, but generate a error.

This is the method in java

```
public void addNewProduct(String idProduct, String productURL) {
        DTOOutProduct dtoOutProduct = new DTOOutProduct();      
        dtoOutProduct.setId(idProduct);
        dtoOutProduct.setName(productURL);
        dtoOutProductsList.add(dtoOutProduct);
}
```

and this is the rule in the Drools decision table in excel file

offerProduct.addNewProduct("$1","$2");

the options are 2 strings with this format:

"string 1","String 2"

Error while creating KieBase[Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=rules.xls, line=93, column=0
   text=Unable to determine the used declarations.
java.lang.NullPointerException], Message [id=2, level=ERROR, path=rules.xls, line=116, column=0
   text=Unable to determine the used declarations.
java.lang.NullPointerException], Message [id=3, level=ERROR, path=rules.xls, line=126, column=0
   text=Unable to determine the used declarations.
java.lang.NullPointerException], Message [id=4, level=ERROR, path=rules.xls, line=103, column=0
   text=Rule Compilation error Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
Syntax error, insert ") Statement" to complete IfStatement
Syntax error on token "Cash", ( expected
Incompatible operand types String and boolean
Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

Answer (score 0):

interesting issue, if your column header/definition is exactly `offerProduct.addNewProduct("$1","$2");` please be sure you put values into data section without quotes, it means, `string 1, string 2`